# Heroku: 'Model Name' is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have developed a rails app and I am now deploying to heroku. In the app, I have a 'Find' model and associated controllers. However, 'Find' is not a database table (it is not apart of the schema.). I made the 'Find' model in order to write class methods and what not. I assume this is why I am getting this error:

```
2012-09-08T10:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
2012-09-08T10:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:5783
2012-09-08T10:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-09-08T10:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-09-08T10:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2012-09-08T10:12:15+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/find.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Find is not a class (TypeError)
2012-09-08T10:12:15+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
```

While I could always just move my "Find" methods into the find controller, I would rather keep it the way it is. Does anyone know how I could resolve this?

My 'find.rb' file:

```
class Find < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.someMethod()
        ...
    end

    def self.someOtherMethod()
        ...
    end

end
```

Note that this setup works fine locally.

Comment: Does it need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` ?

Comment: There is no need to inherit from ActiveRecord::Base if you use tableless model.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if [Active Attr](https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr) does the work. There's also a railscast out there:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr